# list of ordered pairs in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to implement a prolog method that will take a number and return a list of all possible ordered pairs where both X and Y are less than the number given. For example

```
genXY(2,R).
```

Should return

```
R=[0,0];
R=[0,1];
R=[1,0];
R=[1,1].
```

I am having trouble understanding how to implement this. I have written the code

```
genN(N,R) :-
    N1 is N-1,
    between(0,N1,R).
```

Which will give the following output when executed

```
genN(3,R).
R=0;
R=1;
R=2;
```

And I believe that I should use forall to implement genXY but I don't understand how I would go about doing this

Comment: What exactly means "ordered pairs up to that number"? How does that correspond to the example you have given (0-0, 0-1, 1-0, 1-1)? Do you mean "pairs X-Y so that X+Y=0..N"?

Comment: As in if i am given the number 2 I need to return every possible combination of ordered pairs where both X and Y are less then 2. Hence 0-0, 0-1, 1-0, 1-1.

Comment: So you want the lists of N numbers between 0 et N-1. Hint : look at the lists of N numbers between 0 and P-1. How to apply recursion?

Comment: I don't just what the list I want every possible combination. Also what is P-1 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `between/3` twice:

```
?- N = 2, R = X-Y, succ(N0, N), between(0, N0, X), between(0, N0, Y).

R = 0-0;
R = 0-1;
R = 1-0;
R = 1-1;
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me thank you except for one issue. I changed the line setof(X-Y,   to setof([X,Y]   to match the required format however this returns [0, 0] instead of [0,0]. How can I fix this

Comment: This is giving me the same issue, I am going to go back and edit the question to show the issue better

Comment: @JamesNotaro: There is no difference between `[0, 0]` and `[0,0]` - it's just a different way of printing the very same term. Proof: `?- [0, 0] = [0,0].` succeeds

Comment: O ok thank you I am sorry I'm very new to prolog. Thank you for the quick and helpful responses